# loading images in laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel

Strange stuff going on here. For some reason the image loads correctly on one page, however the exact code im using does not work on the other page.

Code that works: index.blade.php

```
@if(count($posts) > 1)
    @foreach($posts as $post)
        <div class= "well">
            <h2><a href="/posts/{{$post->id}}">{{$post->title}}</a></h2>
            <small>{{$post->body}}</small>      
            <br>
            <img src="{{$post->image}}" alt="profile Pic" height="200" width="200">
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        @endforeach
```

Code that does not work: Show.blade.php

```
<h1>{{$post->title}} </h1>
<br>
<h2>{{$post->body}}</h2>  
<br>
<img src="{{$post->image}}" alt="profile Pic" height="250" width="250">
<div class= 'Info'>
<br>
```

PostsController.php

```
      public function show($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $review = Review::all()->where('post_id', $id);
    return view('posts.show', compact('post', 'review'));



}
```

Im having issues with the img src part on show.blade.php. Everything else such as title and body is showing but the image on that page is not. Does anyone have this issue ?

Comment: What is value of $post->image? pls tell

Comment: Could you plz add your model / controller

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI please see edited code

Comment: @cutesengh Give us example value of `$post->image`

Comment: Is it from database upload using `Storage` or another method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `url` method to get the URL for the given file.

```
<img src="{{ Storage::url($post->image) }}" alt="profile Pic" height="250" width="250">
```

---

Also, to make `public` disk accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`.

To create the symbolic link, you may use the `storage:link` Artisan command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

---

Answer (score 0):

The most common mistake in this problem is that do not pay attention to `relative path`.

Use absolute path for it.And you can use `Inspect element` of browser for compare 2 pages data.